# error: could not find .plist file after upgrading to iOS 9

Tags: plist, ios9

Project builds and runs perfectly on iOS 8 devices and simulators. But running on iOS 9 device gives and error: Could not find Root.plist.
plist will ne selected as per the preferred language(english or mandarin).

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"bundle"];
     path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]  stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"lproj"]];
     path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Root.plist"];
```

[my files in project nav window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sf50.png)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue
[NSLocale preferredLanguages] in previous versions of iOS return "en" for english and iOS 9 returns "en-US". So the path created was wrong and the file was not found

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"bundle"];
    NSString *lang = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

    /*iOS 9 fix as lang for ios 9 returns en-US*/
    if ([lang isEqualToString:@"en-US"]) {
        lang = @"en";
    }

    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[lang stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"lproj"]];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Root.plist"];
```